# I get "ConfigError: Missing region in config" when I use AWS SES to send an email

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-ses

I'm using node and next js.
I wrote a function to send an email when someone subscribes to a newsletter; it sends a welcome email. The error comes out when I call the function.

In terms of what I tried to fix this credentials problem:

1. I used the "aws configure" command that the aws cli provides.
2. I used a .env file with the credentials.
3. I set the enviroment variables on my pc via the set command (this did set them up but I still have the problem).

Currently I'm using this on top of my function (I'm trying to make it work with the .env file):

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk")
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION
})
```

Something that might be useful is that when I use console.log to log out the enviroment variables the result is "undefined". I tested it out with another enviroment variable (NODE_ENV) and it does come out correctly.

Comment: you need to include [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package

Comment: I did include dotenv package before (and after just to rule out any problem with that) and didn't help